# identify a sprite inside a closed loop drawn by placing sprites along the touchesMoved method

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have drawn a closed loop using touchesMoved method, placing sprites along the way ,now I want to find out if there are any sprites object enclosed by that closed loop. Is there any function to find it, if not how else can I implement this... Thanks in advance .

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint

Comment: @0x141E this wouldnt work for me. i am not using paths, I am drawing a closed loop by placing sprites along the touched moved method

Comment: You can also create a CGPath (that's not drawn) to determine if a sprite is in the closed loop. Since the shape of the loop is arbitrary, it's not easy to code up a test for that. I suggest you use what's available in the system.